# Why doesn't the coriolis force cancel out when a ball is thrown up?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, projectile, coriolis-effect

The question is to calculate the lateral displacement of a ball due to the coriolis force once thrown up and allowed to come back down.

The initial equation to work with is $\ddot{x} = -2\omega \dot{z} cos(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the latitude of the thrower on Earth and $z$ and $x$ are directed upwards and east respectively. This gives:
$$x = -2\omega cos(\lambda) (\sqrt{gh/2} t^2 - gt^3/6)$$

I understand that the maths gives the displacement of the ball by putting into this the time it takes for the ball to reach the ground ($x(2v_0/g)$), but as the coriolis force acts west when the stone goes upwards and east when downwards, why is there a displacement at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before looking into the details of the calculation let me first discuss what is physically happening.

As usual in cases like this, effects from friction are neglected.

From the moment that the ball is released the motion of the ball is orbital motion; the ball is in a [Kepler orbit](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/kepler.html) around the Earth's center of gravity. It's just that the orbit is at such low altitude that within seconds the ball is back at the surface.

The ball climbs up to its highest altitude and is curved back again. As we know, orbital motion is characterized by conservation of angular momentum. At the point of release the ball had the same angular velocity as the Earth itself. During the climb to its highest altitude the angular velocity of the ball is decreasing. So as the ball climbs its position relative to the longitude of release starts to lag behind. On the way down the angular velocity picks up again, and at the moment of reaching the surface the angular velocity is back to what it was at the moment of release. Still, all the way up and down the angular velocity of the ball was slower than the angular velocity of the Earth, so all the way up and down there was continuous accumulation of lagging behind.

But hang on, if you would drop a ball from a tower, you would find that it lands *east* from the base of the tower. Shouldn't the way up and the way down cancel each other?

The difference: when you throw it up then at the moment of highest altitude the ball is *not stationary with respect to the Earth*. At the point of highest altitude the ball has a smaller angular velocity than the Earth. On the other hand, the ball that is released from a tower has at the moment of release the same angular velocity as the Earth.

An exhaustive calculation would use orbital mechanics, but yeah, in this case that would be overkill.

To a sufficient approximation the gravitational acceleration is the same from the surface to the point of highest altitude, so you can simply use a a constant gravitational acceleration.

The expression with the Coriolis term is exactly correct in the case where the centripetal force increases in proportion to the distance to the center of rotation. Well, the ball is thrown up at most 10 meters or so. That means the centrifugal term in the equation of motion changes hardly at all, so you can treat it as a constant.

In this calculation the centrifugal term is implicitly included. The value of $g$ that is used is the effective gravitational acceleration. The effective gravitational acceleration is the resultant of the true gravity of the Earth and the centrifugal effect arising from the Earth's rotation.

This tells you where the approximation will fail. An exhaustive calculation uses the inverse square law of gravity, and an explicit centrifugal term.